# getJSON wont allow array to pass through

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function near_home(lat,long,miles) {
  var url = "api_url";
  var places = [];

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data['results'], function(i, place) {
      places.push(place);
    });
    console.log(places);
  });
  console.log(places);
  return places;
}
```

So the first console.log() will return the desired objects. But the second console method results in null data. I've rewritten this thing a few times over and can't seem to find reason for this madness. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX requests are asynchronous. You need to execute all following code in a callback.

A possible solution would be this:

```
function near_home(lat,long,miles,cb) {
    var url = "api_url";
    var places = [];

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data.results, function(i, place) {
            places.push(place);
        });
        cb(places);
    });
}
```

When using the function, call it like this:

```
near_home(lat, long, miles, function(places) {
    // your code using the returned array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getJSON()` method is asynchronous so places will not have been filled at the second console.log-statement.